# regexp keep/match any word that starts with a certain character

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'd like to keep only the string that starts with # or @

1. foobar @sushi - wasabi
2. foobar #sushi - horseradish

Therefore match on only **@susui** or remove text around it. PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you define a "word", you probably want

```
(?<=\s|^)[@#]\S+
```

or

```
(?<=\s|^)[@#]\w+
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\s|^)  # Assert that the previous character is a space (or start of string)
[@#]       # Match @ or #
\S+        # Match one or more non-space characters
(or \w+)   # Match one or more alphanumeric characters.
```

So, in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\s|^)[@#]\S+/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

gives you an array `$result` of all the matches in the string `$subject`. In JavaScript, this won't work because lookbehinds (the "Assert..." part from the start of the regex) are not supported.