# Javascript Regex match any word that starts with '#' in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new at regex. I'm trying to match any word that starts with '#' in a string that contains no newlines (content was already split at newlines).

Example (not working):

```
var string = "#iPhone should be able to compl#te and #delete items"
var matches = string.match(/(?=[\s*#])\w+/g)
// Want matches to contain [ 'iPhone', 'delete' ]
```

I am trying to match any instance of '#', and grab the thing right after it, so long as there is at least one letter, number, or symbol following it. A space or a newline should end the match. The '#' should either start the string or be preceded by spaces.

This PHP solution seems good, but it uses a look backwards type of functionality that I don't know if JS regex has:
[regexp keep/match any word that starts with a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171305/regexp-keep-match-any-word-that-starts-with-a-certain-character)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var re = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g, match, matches = [];
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

Check **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BUC7L/)**.

```js
let s = "#hallo, this is a test #john #doe",
  re = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g,
  match, matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: edited version returns the ' #' preceding each tag: "Grocery #Shopping #list".match(/(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g)
[" #Shopping", " #list"]

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe - You took a regex pattern from my answer and used `match` with it, but that is not what is in my answer. My code works with group #1 to get results you wanted. See demo link in my answer to see results...

Comment: Oh, clever. So this depends on the way .exec returns matches, huh? Kinda cool

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe - Check documentation to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var matches = string.match(/#\w+/g);
```

```js
let string = "#iPhone should be able to compl#te and #delete items",
  matches = string.match(/#\w+/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Ah my bad. I didn't know you don't want the #.

Comment: This will also pick up # anywhere in the word, not just at the start of the word.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to match the hash too. Right now you're looking for word characters that follow a *position* that is immediately followed by one of several characters that aren't word characters. This fails, for obvious reasons. Try this instead:

```
string.match(/(?=[\s*#])[\s*#]\w+/g)
```

Of course, the lookahead is redundant now, so you might as well remove it:

```
string.match(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g).map(function(v){return v.trim().substring(1);})
```

This returns the desired: `[ 'iPhone', 'delete' ]`

Here is a demonstration:  http://jsfiddle.net/w3cCU/1/

Comment: You don't need a capture group in the second example.

Comment: This returns the hash, and then it's substringed. Why not use this one, if we have to substring it anyway? "Grocery #Shopping #list".match(/#\w+/g).map(function(v){return v.substring(1);})

Comment: This fails for words that have embedded `#` (e.g.: "Don't #find this#one but only #this")

Comment: @TedHopp Actually don't want to grab '#' if it's embedded

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe It is the simplest regex possible. I assure you I did not need to rip off vaidik. The key part here is the array map anyway.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Doesn't match embedded hashes now.

Comment: Works exactly awesome, Asad, thank you. I'm hoping there's a method that does it without the substring, but I don't know enough about regex to know if that's possible. I see a lookahead (?=) operator, but not a lookback.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe All of this could have been avoided with a simple lookbehind, but javascript doesn't have those.