# Javascript or Jquery to match var string from a string content and starts with var string

Tags: jquery, pattern-matching

I have variables:

```
var string_content = "This is a stackoverflow sentence pattern match";
var keyword = "mat";
```

I need to check if the 'keyword' matches any string from the string_content that starts with "mat".

Result: 1 match (mat ~ match)

if keyword is "overflow", then it should not generate a result because there's no match starting with every word with "overflow" from string_content.

I re-used this code from the other post -

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(keyword) {
return function( string_content ) {
return $(string_content).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(keyword.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

});
```

but it returns a result, but not the start with pattern (i.e. keyword = mat).

Any help will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is regular epressions you can read up on it on the following link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Here is a SO link as well to help you along [Javascript Regex match any word that starts with '#' in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554208/javascript-regex-match-any-word-that-starts-with-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/RdwP4/)):

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (keyword) {
    return function (string_content) {
        return new RegExp( '\\b' + keyword, 'i' ).test( $(string_content).text() );
    };
});
```

I believe naming the function `contains` will override the built-in jQuery `:contains()` selector, so you might consider renaming it.

Comment: Actually, the key part is the `\b` within the regexp which looks for a break in the word.