# Javascript : Extract words starting with specific character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm having this string :

```
Hey I love #apple and #orange and also #banana
```

I would like to extract every words that start with the `#` symbol.

Currently I'm achieving it with this code :

```
var last = 0;
var n = 0;
var str = "Hey I love #apple and #orange and also #banana";
do{
    n = str.indexOf("#", last);
    if(n != -1){
        //The code found the # char at position 'n'
        last = n+1; //saving the last found position for next loop

        //I'm using this to find the end of the word
        var suffixArr = [' ', '#'];
        var e = -1;
        for(var i = 0; i < suffixArr.length;i++){
            if(str.indexOf(suffixArr[i], n) != -1){
               e = str.indexOf(suffixArr[i], n+1);
               break;
            }
        }
        if(e == -1){
            //Here it could no find banana because there isn't any white space or # after
            e = str.length; //this is the only possibility i've found
        }

        //extracting the word from the string
        var word = str.substr(n+1, (e-1)-n);
   }
}
while (n != -1);
```

How can I manage to find words starting with # and with `a-Z characters` only. If for example I have `#apple!` i should be able to extract `apple`
And also, as I mentionned in the code, how do I manage to get the word if it appears at the end of the string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554208/javascript-regex-match-any-word-that-starts-with-in-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(?:^|[ ])#([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/18

```
    var re = /(?:^|[ ])#([a-zA-Z]+)/gm;
var str = 'Hey I love #apple and #orange and #apple!@ also #banana';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: You can easily replace "#" with blank value and get the remaining string. Solution from VKS will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really need to learn regexp by the time..:)

Comment: @vks: i want to know why added `^|` because we are also able to get space using `?:[ ]`  Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if the word is at start of sentence ,there wont be a space behind it.For that case i have added `^|`

Comment: @vks How can I also get if someone writes `#orange#apple`. Your code only shows `orange` currently. I tryed by removing the `(?:^|[ ])` in the regexp but want to be sure

Comment: @BobbyShark use `#([a-zA-Z]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/(^|\s)#[a-z]+/i` and `match` it and then make use of `Array.join`(here it is being used internally when `+ ""` executed) and replace all the `#` from the formed String and split on `,`

```
var arr = (str.match(/(^|\s)#[a-z]+/i)+"").replace(/#/g,"").split(",");
```

If you also want to match `test` in `Some#test`, then remove the `(^|\s)` from the regex.