# How do I find words starting with a specific letter?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, cpu-word

I want to find words which start with a specific letter in a string using the following code. The specific letter would be supplied by the user in a text box.

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="srch" type="text" />
<button onClick=searchword()>Search</button>

<p id="wrd" > hallo, this is a test john doe .
Another tea house pole.
</p>

</body>

<script>

function searchword() {

var s = document.getElementById("wrd").innerHTML;
var p= document.getElementById("srch").value;

var regx = new RegExp("(?:^|\W)" + p + "(\w+)(?!\w)","gi");

var re = regx, match, matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
}
alert(matches);


}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use regexp `\bW[^\b\s]+\gi ` to find words starting on "W" or "w".

Comment: How do I insert the first letter of the word which is supplied by the user  i.e.  'W' in your example in the regular expression? ,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I got the following answer and its working,thanks

var regx = new RegExp("(\\b"+p+"\\S+\\b)","ig");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : Extract words starting with specific character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739496/javascript-extract-words-starting-with-specific-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b`, the following example shows how to match every word starting with `t`

```js
var string ="hallo, this is a test john doe .Another tea house pole. Hey Tom."
result = string.match(/(\bt\S+\b)/ig);
//result = string.match(/(\st\S+)/ig); // alternative
document.write(result);
```

Comment: How do I insert the first letter of the word which is supplied by the user  i.e.  't' in your example in the regular expression? ,

Comment: I got the following answer and its working, thanks                                                                                var regx = new RegExp("(\\b"+p+"\\S+\\b)","ig");

Comment: Not working when there are special characters before the letter "t". For example it will match a work like "étonnant".

Comment: @Liam You can also try: `result = string.match(/(\st\S+)/ig);` to avoid false matches like `tonnant`

Answer (score -1):

```
var string ="hallo, this is a test john doe .Another tea house pole. Hey 
Tom."
result = string.match(/(\ba\S+\b)/ig);
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.